# Adding a text to the QTabWidget

Tags: qt, user-interface, qtabwidget

I have class which inherits `QTabWidget`. Inside the generated tab I want to display some text.The text should not be editable by the user.But during the application execution there can be a case/s which will cause the text change. Which class should I use for text? Thought about `QTextEdit` - but it doesn`t look like best idea - since the user should not change the text.Also thought about `QLabel` - but it also is not good - since the application displays text not label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTextEdit` can be set to read-only with its property `readOnly`. I use `QTextEdit` to display a long read-only text, because it can scroll. I also have read-write text, and by choosing the same widget for all long text, my user interface looks even.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#readOnly-prop

An other alternative is `QWebView` if you plan to have complexly formatted text.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html

Comment: Sо why it better then QtextLabel?

Comment: Does `QTextLabel` even exist? I can't find it in the QT docs. However `QLabel` can't scroll IMHO, and by default looks different than `QTextEdit`. But there is no specific downside to displaying text with a `QLabel`.